# SSL error on tornado server

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, tornado

I'm trying to make a HTTPS web server.  Here is my code...

```
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import settings
import os
import ssl

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/login', LoginPage),
        ]
        args = {
            'template_path': settings.TEMPLATE_PATH,
            'static_path': settings.STATIC_PATH,
            'debug': True,
            'cookie_secret': settings.COOKIE_SECRET,
            'login_url': settings.LOGIN_URL,
        }

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **args)

class LoginPage(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("SSL. Yay!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    applicaton = Application()
    ssl_options = {'certfile': os.path.join(settings.SSL_PATH, 'certificate.crt'),
                   'keyfile': os.path.join(settings.SSL_PATH, 'privateKey.key'),
    }
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(applicaton, ssl_options=ssl_options)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I generated my certificate.crt and privateKey.key using the following command...

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
```

When I run the server and go to localhost:8888/login I get the following error...

```
/usr/bin/python2 /home/user/dev/sslserver/main.py
WARNING:root:SSL Error on 9 ('127.0.0.1', 55303): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
WARNING:root:SSL Error on 10 ('127.0.0.1', 55304): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
WARNING:root:SSL Error on 9 ('127.0.0.1', 55305): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
```

If I remove the ssl_options=ssl_options the webpage displays fine.  Am I missing an argument for ssl_options?  I'm new to certificates and ssl so any advice on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly go to `https://localhost:8888` (not just `localhost:8888`).  Without the https:// prefix, the browser is sending unencrypted http; that's what the "http request" error message from openssl means.  You can't serve http and https on the same port, but you can start up a second HTTPServer without ssl_options on a different port.

Comment: This works.  Now I just need to figure out how to force https when a user just enters http.  Right now if a user enters mydomain:8888 it defaults to http and the web page does not load.  I need it to redirect them to https.  Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: You can't. HTTP and HTTPS must use different ports, and there is no practical way to make incorrect urls work. If you run on the default ports of 80/443 then the browser will know to switch ports automatically, but for non-default ports the browser will do exactly what you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use SSL to a `localhost` hostname connection. SSL + HTTPS use a certificate with your domain name, and use this to provide authentication.

Since you are connecting to `localhost`, your hostname (localhost) will not match the hostname on the certificate and you will receive a certificate error.

There are some ways to hack around this, but I would just non-SSL (regular HTTP) on your local machine, and then when you push to your server (with your proper domain name), you can enable SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I figured this out almost immediately after I posted the reply.  SSL works on a remote machine if I explicitly specify https in the URL.